# Prepend if statement with Fancybox

Tags: php, jquery, if-statement, fancybox, meta-boxes

Hi I'm using Fancybox and a couple of custom metaboxes to display either a PDF document or a embedded video. When it's a PDF embed I'm using beforeShow to prepend fancybox so it shows a link to open the PDF full screen this works great as below:

```
<script>
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
openEffect  : 'none',
closeEffect : 'none',
padding : [0, 15, 15, 15],
 helpers : {
        title : null
    },
    'scrolling'   : 'no',
   beforeShow   : function() {
    this.inner.prepend( '<a class="full-screen" href="http://www.iofpi.co.uk/civicworks.net/wp-content/plugins/pdfjs-viewer-shortcode/web/viewer.php?file=<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wpb_arch', true ); ?>">View PDF Full Screen</a>' );
},
iframe : {
    preload: false
}

});
</script>
```

However, what I'd like to do now is have it check to see which custom metabox is filled and only show the view full screen link if it's the PDF and not the video field. Something like below, but, I just can't get it to work, it shows nothing.

```
    <script>
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
openEffect  : 'none',
closeEffect : 'none',
padding : [0, 15, 15, 15],
 helpers : {
        title : null
    },
    'scrolling'   : 'no',
    beforeShow   : function() {
    this.inner.prepend( '<?php $pdfhref = get_post_meta( $child_page->ID, '_wpb_arch', true ); if ( $pdfhref  ) { ?>
<a class="full-screen" href="http://www.iofpi.co.uk/civicworks.net/wp-content/plugins/pdfjs- viewer-shortcode/web/viewer.php?file=<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wpb_arch', true ); ?>">View PDF Full Screen</a>
<?php } ?>' );
},
iframe : {
    preload: false
}

});
</script>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sussed it! For anyone else struggling with this here's how I did it by checking if the element had a certain class before the prepend.

```
    <script>
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
openEffect  : 'none',
closeEffect : 'none',
padding : [0, 15, 15, 15],
 helpers : {
        title : null
    },
    'scrolling'   : 'no',
   beforeShow   : function() {
    if ($(this.element).hasClass('pdf')) {
    this.inner.prepend( '<a class="full-screen"  href="http://www.iofpi.co.uk/civicworks.net/wp-content/plugins/pdfjs-viewer-shortcode/web/viewer.php?file=<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wpb_arch', true ); ?>">View PDF Full Screen</a>' );
}
  },
iframe : {
    preload: false
}
});
</script>
```